# How is $\sin 45^\circ=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, proof-verification, triangles, alternative-proof

I've been reading about the proof of $\sin 45^\circ=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ in my book. They did it as following, let $\triangle ABC$ be an isosceles triangle as shown,

[image: Triangle]

Since the triangle is isosceles with base and perpendicular equal the [opposite angle $\angle C$ and $\angle B$ must be equal](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Isosceles_Triangle_has_Two_Equal_Angles). Putting $\angle A=90^\circ$ and using $\angle A + \angle B + \angle C = 180^0$, we get $\angle A= \angle B= 45^\circ$. Now using Pythagoras theorem gives $\sin 45^\circ = \dfrac {1}{\sqrt 2}$. I am satisfied with this explanation. But on https://proofwiki.org they used a square to prove this formula as shown: [image: SQUARE]

[In that proof over proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sine_of_45_Degrees/Proof_1) they say that the $\angle A$ is $45^\circ$ because the diagonal $AC$ is the bisector of $\angle A$. They do not use the property of isosceles triangle. My questions are,

- Why is the diagonal of a square bisector of the angle from which it originates? How can we prove this mathematically?
- Are there some other geometric proofs of $\sin 45^\circ=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}$?

Answer (score 6):

You can prove that the two isosceles triangles are congruent by SSS, and hence the angles adding up to 90 are equal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was quit simple.

Answer (score 2):

The angle bisector is exactly the line of points equidistant from the two lines it bisects. The distance of $C$ to $AB$ is $BC$ and the distance of $C$ to $AD$ is $CD$. Since $ABCD$ is a square, $BC=CD$ and thus $C$ lies on the angle bisector. Now since the angle bisector also goes through $A$, it must be exactly the line $AC$.

Concerning other proofs, here's another, albeit similar, proof: It is clear from the same construction that $\sin{45^\circ} = \cos{45^\circ}$. Now since

$$\left(\sin\theta\right)^2+\left(\cos\theta\right)^2=1$$

we get:

$$2\left(\sin{45^\circ}\right)^2=1\Rightarrow\sin{45^{\circ}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$

observing that it must be positive.

Comment: I don't get it. Perpendicular bisector of what?

Comment: @user103816 Sorry, I'm tired and horrible at English. The angle bisector.

Comment: Are there some other geometric proofs for it?

Comment: @user103816 Of course. You can do something very similar to what David Quinn did.

Comment: I mean some thing else than these methods.

Comment: @user103816 There are a bunch, and they are not hard to come up with, but most of them will are similar in idea to the answers you already got. That is, you construct some triangle and look at the relevant ratios.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the diagonal of a square bisector of the angle from which it originates? How can we prove this mathematically?

Let $ABCD$ be a square. We know that two triangles $\triangle{ABD},\triangle{CBD}$ are congruent because $AB=CB,AD=CD,\angle{BAD}=\angle{BCD}$. Now we have $$\angle{ADB}=\angle{CDB}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was quit simple.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite elementary, my dear Watson. $ABCD$ is a square. More generally, it's a rhombus, and the following applies to that also: $AB ≅ AD$, $BC ≅ DC$, $CA ≅ CA$, thus $△ABC ≅ △ADC$; and from this, it follows $∠BAC = ∠DAC$.

This proves that the $90^∘$ right angle $∠BAD$ is bisected, thereby showing that both $∠BAC$ and $∠DAC$ are both $45^∘$ angles.

You would do better to consider the fact that since
$$\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = 1, \quad \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x = \cos{2x},$$
then
$$2\cos^2 x = 1 + \cos{2x},$$
from which it follows that
$$\cos x = ±\sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos{2x}}{2}},$$
and likewise when $x$ is divided by $2$:
$$\cos \frac{x}{2} = ±\sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos{2x}}{2}},$$
For angles $x$ between $0^∘$ and $90^∘$, inclusive, $\cos x ≥ 0$, so that we always have
$$\cos \frac{x}{2} = +\sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos{2x}}{2}} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2 + 2\cos{2x}}.$$

Therefore, we can iterate and interpolate, starting with
$$\cos 0^∘ = 1, \quad \cos 90^∘ = 0.$$

In the first round, we get:
$$\cos 45^∘ = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2 + 2·0} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}.$$

In the second round, making use of complements ($\cos{135^∘} = -\cos{45^∘}$), we get:
$$\cos 22½^∘ = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}, \quad \cos 67½^∘ = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}}.$$

In the third round, again making use of complements ($\cos 112½^∘ = -\cos 67½^∘$ and $\cos 157½^∘ = -\cos 22½^∘$), we get:
$$
\cos 11¼^∘ = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}}, \quad \cos 33¾^∘ = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}}},\\
\cos 56¼^∘ = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}}}, \quad \cos 78¾^∘ = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}}.
$$

In the fourth round, once more making use of complements ($\cos 101¼^∘ = -\cos 78¾^∘$, $\cos 123¾^∘ = -\cos 56¼^∘$, $\cos 146¼^∘ = -\cos 33¾^∘$ and $\cos 168¾^∘ = -\cos 11¼^∘$), we get:
$$
\cos 5⅝^∘ = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}}}, \quad \cos 16⅞^∘ = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}}}},\\
\cos 28⅛^∘ = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}}}}, \quad \cos 39⅜^∘ = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}}},\\
\cos 50⅝^∘ = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}}}, \quad \cos 61⅞^∘ = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}}}},\\
\cos 73⅛^∘ = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}}}}, \quad \cos 84⅜^∘ = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}}}.
$$

And so on...

It goes without saying that $0^∘$ and $90^∘$ fit within this scheme with:
$$
1 = \cos 0^∘ = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + ⋯}}}}},\\
0 = \cos 90^∘ = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + ⋯}}}}}.
$$